# Publish app on Google Play

Tags: android, encryption, key, publish

I am going to publish an application on the Google Play market. For this I will create an encrypted key. For future updates I know I have to use the same key to sign the apk.

Do I also need to use the same machine I created the key or the only requirement is to have the same key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to use the same key with the same profile. You can sign it from a machine built on Mars, and Google Play won't say a thing. However, even one small change in the key will result in an error.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the same encrypted key. (keystore)
And the package name must be same.
There no other requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to have the key file and know its password, check this [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)